# How to exclude some users from Linux Top screen?

Tags: linux, users, top

In `top` screen, by default it shows all users' processes. How to exclude some users(for example, root and nobody) from the top real-time screen?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The correct answer is: `-U '!root'` (or `-u '!root'` on some Ubuntus). This was introduced in top v3.2.9:

`man top` for -U option:

> Prepending  an  exclamation  point ('!') to the user id or name instructs top to display only processes with users not matching the one provided.

Remember to put the exclamation mark and username in single quotes.

Comment: Please note this works on the more recent versions of `top`. 3.3.9 has it, while 3.2.8 hasn't.

Comment: Oddly enough, on Ubuntu 14.04, I needed to use `-u` instead of `-U`.

Comment: I had to use `top -u '!root'` to NOT get the `!` to be interpreted by the shell (I believe that is what is happening w/o the single quotes).

Comment: Interactively you can type `u` and then `!root`

Comment: Better yet, add a filter to exclude all system users, like `O` and filter `RUID>999`. You need to add `RUID` column first.

Comment: `sudo top -u '!root'` worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Also, as of version 3.3, you can just type `u` while `top` is running and enter that `!root` string.

Answer (score 2):

`top -U root` shows only processes from root. Unfortunately that is the only option for limiting users according to the man page.

Comment: But if you wanted to deviate from using top, you could do `ps aux | grep -v $USERNAME` to see all processes except the user you specified.

Comment: Thanks. I know those two commands. I've searched around but didn't find anyone ask about this. top -u can see one user, but I want to see more users in real-time.

Comment: top | egrep -ve "(root|knoppix)"? Modify to suit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Dr Beco](https://serverfault.com/questions/347404/how-to-exclude-some-users-from-linux-top-screen#comment1081846_626170) above the most general filtering mechanism uses 'o/O' to activate "Other Filtering" while in `top` to exclude/include more than one user.

For example to exclude "root" and "nobody" one can use the command `o!USER=root<enter>o!USER=nobody`.

Many interesting views are possible with this filtering option!

Comment: I think this is the only answer that answers the question: "exclude some users (for example, root and nobody)", i.e. excluding more than one user. Perhaps this wasn't possible in 2012.